# Access to the path Server.MapPath is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I created one  pdf document

```
        var document = new Document();
        string path = Server.MapPath("AttachementToMail");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + 
                  "/"+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Now I want to download this document

```
 Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+   
                                DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".pdf" + "");
 Response.TransmitFile(path);
 Response.End();
```

but it gave me error
**Access to the path '~\AttachementToMail' is denied.**

read / write access for IIS_IUSRS exists

Comment: Server.MapPath returns the absolute path to the directory, but you're providing us with a virtual path. Are you sure that you've expanded the `path` by the time you invoke `TransmitFile`?

Comment: Obvious question, but *does* the account running the site have access to that folder? Also: can you say **explicitly** which line throws ? is it the `string path = Server.MapPath("AttachementToMail")` ? Also: is this just a typo issue? is the directory actually `AttachmentToMail` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell error is on line Response.TransmitFile(path);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are providing to write is a virtual path. `TransmitFile` expects an absolute path.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var document = new Document();
string path = Server.MapPath("AttachementToMail");
var fileName =  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".pdf";
var fullPath = path + "\\" + fileName;

//Write it to disk
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));

//Send it to output
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName );

Response.TransmitFile(fullPath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

`DateTime.Now` represents the current time. Be careful when you use it as the file name. 
Using `ToShortDateString` is a little risky, as some cultures put `/` in that format. Using `ToString` will allow you to fix your filename format regardless of the server culture.

Comment: after Response.TransmitFile(fullPath);Response.End(); the document does not download

Comment: Put a `Response.Flush();` before the `Response.End();`

Comment: I added  Response.Flush(); but still not working :(  document is created but does not download